# Error in downloading csv from new Yahoo Finance historical data

Tags: csv, cookies, yahoo-finance

I've tried to make some code work for the new yahoo finances historical data now that the old API is officially dead.  Code is as follows:

```
Private Function DownloadData(ByVal StockSymbol As String)

    Try

        'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/CPG.TO?period1=1492824351&period2=1495416351&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=M3Ig5MvcK77

        Dim Period1 As Integer = (New DateTime(2007, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) - New DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds
        Dim Period2 As Integer = (DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds

        Dim csvData As String = String.Empty

        Using Web As New WebClient

            Dim strm As Stream = Web.OpenRead("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & StockSymbol & "/history?p=" & StockSymbol)

            Dim Crumb As String = ScrapeCrumb(strm)

            Dim s As String = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" & StockSymbol &
                                "?period1=" & Period1.ToString & "&period2=" & Period2.ToString & "&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=" & Crumb
            csvData = Web.DownloadString(s)

        End Using

        Return csvData

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return String.Empty

    End Try

End Function
Private Function ScrapeCrumb(ByVal strm As Stream) As String

    Try

        Dim Output As String = String.Empty

        Using sr As New StreamReader(strm)
            Output = sr.ReadToEnd()
            ' Close and clean up the StreamReader
            sr.Close()
        End Using

        Dim Result As String = Output.Remove(0, Output.IndexOf("CrumbStore"))
        Result = Result.Remove(0, 22)
        Result = Result.Remove(Result.IndexOf("}"), Result.Length - Result.IndexOf("}"))
        Result = Result.Remove(Result.Length - 1, 1)

        Return Result

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return String.Empty

    End Try

End Function
```

But I keep getting the error

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I feel like it has to do with the cookies/crumb deal but I am scraping it so I'm not sure why this is not giving permission to download the file.  Does anybody have any ideas?

EDIT: Using vb language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got error "(401) Unauthorized" because you do not have a valid cookie (cookie "B") value.

I managed to work out a .NET class to obtain valid token (cookie and crumb) from Yahoo Finance

For complete API library in fetching historical data from new Yahoo Finance, you may visit [YahooFinanceAPI](https://github.com/dennislwy/YahooFinanceAPI) in Github

Here is the class to grab the cookie and crumb

**Token.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace YahooFinanceAPI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class for fetching token (cookie and crumb) from Yahoo Finance
    /// Copyright Dennis Lee
    /// 19 May 2017
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class Token
    {
        public static string Cookie { get; set; }
        public static string Crumb { get; set; }

        private static Regex regex_crumb;
        /// <summary>
        /// Refresh cookie and crumb value Yahoo Fianance
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="symbol">Stock ticker symbol</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool Refresh(string symbol = "SPY")
        {

            try
            {
                Token.Cookie = "";
                Token.Crumb = "";

                string url_scrape = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}?p={0}";
                //url_scrape = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/history"

                string url = string.Format(url_scrape, symbol);

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                request.Method = "GET";

                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {

                    string cookie = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie").Split(';')[0];

                    string html = "";

                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        html = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                    }

                    if (html.Length < 5000)
                        return false;
                    string crumb = getCrumb(html);
                    html = "";

                    if (crumb != null)
                    {
                        Token.Cookie = cookie;
                        Token.Crumb = crumb;
                        Debug.Print("Crumb: '{0}', Cookie: '{1}'", crumb, cookie);
                        return true;
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }

            return false;

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get crumb value from HTML
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="html">HTML code</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string getCrumb(string html)
        {

            string crumb = null;

            try
            {
                //initialize on first time use
                if (regex_crumb == null)
                    regex_crumb = new Regex("CrumbStore\":{\"crumb\":\"(?<crumb>\\w+)\"}", 
                    RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

                MatchCollection matches = regex_crumb.Matches(html);

                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {
                    crumb = matches[0].Groups["crumb"].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Print("Regex no match");
                }

                //prevent regex memory leak
                matches = null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }

            GC.Collect();
            return crumb;

        }

    }
}
```