# MSXML2.XMLHTTP broken yahoo ticker request

Tags: excel, vba, csv, https

I have a nice VBA script that allowed me to download stock ticker information from Yahoo into Excel.
Yahoo have recently changed their web interface and the download commands that used to work have now ceased to do so.
The previous commands had the following structure:-

"http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=TSCO.L&a=5&b=09&c=2016&d=5&e=26&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv"

where the new commands look like:-

"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TSCO.L?period1=1465456200&period2=1466925000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=Ns6veY6jrcA"

period1 & period2 are epoch representations of the date, and the 'crumb' I believe is unique to each machine that sends a download request to the yahoo server. 
I think this remains the same for a reasonable period of time so it doesn't have to be changed.

If I paste the https request into a browser it works. However the routine that I used to check for the data's existence and to subsequently download the data no longer work.

This is a shortened version of the overall code, if anyone is so good as to try it out, you will probably have to replace my crumb value with your crumb value, this can be found if you follow this link:-
https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSCO.L/history?p=TSCO.L and hover your mouse over the 'Download Data' link.

`Function IsResourceAvailable(strUrl As String) As Boolean

```
Dim objXhr As Object 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim strStatus As String

Set objXhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") 'New XMLHTTP60
With objXhr
    .Open "GET", strUrl, False
    .send
    strStatus = .Status
End With

'HTTP response of 200 = OK
IsResourceAvailable = (strStatus = "200")
```

End Function'

'Sub dloadDebug()

```
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAvailable As Boolean

strUrl = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TSCO.L?period1=1465456200&period2=1466925000&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=Ns6veY6jrcA"

blnAvailable = IsResourceAvailable(strUrl)
Workbooks.Open Filename:=(strUrl)
```

End Sub`

Neither of the above now work, can anybody point me in the right direction please?

many thanks

GLW

Comment: A URL is no longer sufficient on its own, you now need a session cookie as well, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105187/error-in-downloading-csv-from-new-yahoo-finance-historical-data

Comment: Many thanks for that, I dont have visual studio installed so I can't run the .net class. However, I've found that you can see the cookie B value by searching for yahoo cookies in chrome://settings/cookies.

Can i ask, how do you then append the cookie value to the URL string?

Comment: Its a header, so try https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290899/bug-xmlhttp-fails-to-send-cookies-from-a-client